# boto3: pydevd warning: boto3 Getting attribute Image.name was slow

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I have a test script which runs for around 20 minutes.
The AWSSession is initialized at the start of the test and also used in few initial steps.
After around 10 minutes of test execution, the test uses the AWSSession created at the start of the test.
The method which returns the session creates a new session if the token is older than 10 minutes.

When my code tries to get the image name like `ec2_instance.image.name` where `ec2_instance` is the EC2 instance object, it fails with the following warning:
`pydevd warning:  boto3 Getting attribute Image.name was slow`

I have also tried to get the image first using:

```
image = self.ec2_resource.Image(ec2_instance.image_id)
image_name: str = image.name
```

but it still fails with the same warning because of which I am not able to retrieve the image name. When I try to retrieve it, I get the following error:

```
self = ec2.Image(id='ami-0cd653a2ee34f2e96')
    def property_loader(self):
        if self.meta.data is None:
            if hasattr(self, 'load'):
                self.load()
            else:
                raise ResourceLoadException(
                    f'{self.__class__.__name__} has no load method'
                )
    
>       return self.meta.data.get(name)
E       AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/boto3/resources/factory.py:386: AttributeError
```

It seems a bit odd that most of the nested objects, especially the image properties are not loaded.
All the other properties which are not nested don't have any problem being accessed.

It works fine when the property is accessed early in the execution.
I am guessing this is a timing issue where the session is not used for a long time as my code is renewing the token after 10 minutes. I have also tried changing the token renewal time to 5 minutes without luck.

Did anyone have a similar problem?

Boto3 version: 1.24.87

[image]

[image: EC2 Object with Image.name property]

Comment: `fails with the same error` I don't see an error.  I see a warning from `pydevd`.  Are you getting an error?  the ec2 instance data includes an image ID, but not the metadata describing the image such as name, so that requires a different api request.   Could be that it takes even longer because your session is expired, but unless you're actually experiencing an error, I would say pydevd is just wrong about what it expects

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I have updated the description and the error that I get when I try to access the property after the warning. The EC2 instance object has a property `image` under which the `name` property is present.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.
The image that was being used to create the AMI was a private image and AWS was not able to provide the AMI values as seen in the screenshot - `EC2 can't retrieve the name because the AMI was either deleted or made private.`

Sorry for the inconvenience.

[image]